# Ionic Capacitor "PushNotifications" plugin is not implemented on android

Tags: android, firebase, vue.js, ionic-framework

I have a problem when a try to request permissions with `@capacitor/push-notifications` plugin. I followed every step described in the README and I'm using Ionic  and Vue 3.

This is the `package.json`:

```
...
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.3",
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0"
...
```

This is the method that requests the permissions:

```
requestFCMPermissions(context: AuthContext) {
      PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(result => {
        if (result.receive === "granted") {
          PushNotifications.register();
          ...
        } else {
          ...
        }
      });
      ...
}
```

Of course this does not work when a try by Web, but, when I assembly an APK and profile that, it responses me an error in console log:

```
 "PushNotifications" plugin is not implemented on android
```

Anyone know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved my issue editing the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
    // Initializes the Bridge
    this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
      // Additional plugins you've installed go here
      //...
      add(com.capacitorjs.plugins.pushnotifications.PushNotificationsPlugin.class);
    }});
  }
}
```

but this is not specified in any tutorial, so it could be something for my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and was freaking out. Push Notifications were working on the Emulator but not on a real device.

What helped was deleting the android folder. I made a fresh install `cap add android` and I checked the diff using git.

In my case the following line of code in the `app/build.gradle` had to be removed.

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```